# Theoretical Q: From PHP to Specific Part of Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, loops, iteration

Suppose I have the following HTML document that does some sort of simple computation:

```
<html>
<script>

for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
    var x = 2*i;
    // send to PHP
};

</script>
</html>
```

Now suppose I want to save the x-values to a text-file by successively sending the x-values to a separate PHP document (as below), which will append the value to a text-file, and then come back to the HTML to do the next computation in the loop.

```
<?php
    $my_file = 'results.txt';
    $handle = fopen($my_file, 'a') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
    fwrite($handle,$_POST["x"]."\n");
    fclose($handle);
    // go back to HTML document, BUT pick up from i+1 (i.e., don't start over from i=0)
?>
```

Anybody know if this is possible? If so, what should I write in those commented lines? It's important to me that I actually stick to this method of picking up the HTML document at the next value of i (rather than do the whole computation in one PHP file) as this is just a proof of concept.

Comment: Ajax is probably you are looking for

Comment: Definitely AJAX, if you do asynchronous AJAX the loop will continue before the server responds to your HTML page, sychronous will hold the JS execution until the server responds, depends on what you need

Comment: It's probably safe to assume you should probably rethink whatever you're trying to do. Sending 10 ajax requests via a for loop sounds like bad news bears.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use JQuery Ajax. However, it would be best to put all of the x values into an array first, and then send the array. The html/jQuery would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        //intiialize array
        var myArray = [];
        for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
            myArray.push(i); // uses push() method to insert each number to array
        };

        $.post("yourFile.php",
               {TheArray: myArray}, // notice how the array is posted 
            function(response){
                alert(response); //simply alerts the response
            });

    });


    </script>
```

The PHP would be this:

```
<?php

$data = array();

$data = $_REQUEST['TheArray']; // could use post, but request works too

var_dump($data); //cannot echo an array, only strings

?>
```